# How to clean/lint the code in a blazor component with visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I am building my first blazor app and cannot find a way to clean or lint the code for a blazor component (.razor extension).  If I use the "code cleanup" option under the "analyze" menu it doesn't clean the html portion of the file (fix indents etc).  Is there a way to do this with VS2019?

Answer (score 3):

You can hold `Ctrl` and press `K` then `D` to format the code.

This works only for file you are seeing, not sure if there is a way to do this with all the files.

Please notice that this isn't perfect yet and might appear some `/**/` inside you code. But in general, it works.